# MySQL: How to use Stored Procedures to insert rows into different tables?

Tags: mysql

Currently when a new row is inserted into my `users` table I have 1 row inserted into each of these other tables respectively:

```
profiles
user_settings
user_activity
```

Currently I'm doing if from the PHP:

```
$query = mysql_query('INSERT INTO `users` blah blah...');

if($query) {
   mysql_query('INSERT INTO `profiles` blah blah...');
   mysql_query('INSERT INTO `user_settings` blah blah...');
   mysql_query('INSERT INTO `user_activity` blah blah...');
}
```

How can this be done via stored procedures? So that this work will be done by the database server and not the PHP code. Also is there any benefits to doing this from stored procedures vs from code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you are looking for are `triggers` not `stored procedures`. With `triggers` you can execute a query after or before an insert/update/delete query.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-trigger.html

Advantages: It is stored and invoked directly in the DB and I suppose it is more performant as well.

Example:

```
CREATE TRIGGER mytrigger AFTER INSERT ON users
   FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
      INSERT INTO `profiles` blah blah...;
      INSERT INTO `user_settings` blah blah...;
      INSERT INTO `user_activity` blah blah...;
END;
```

Comment: thanks this is what I needed. But how can I grab the id of the just inserted row in the `users` table so that I can use it when inserting a row on one of those other tables? For example my query is `INSERT INTO profiles(user_id) VALUES('???');` what can I replace the ??? with?

Comment: you can use `NEW.id` or whatever your fieldname is `NEW.fieldname`

Comment: from the docs: `You can refer to columns in the subject table (the table associated with the trigger) by using the aliases OLD and NEW. OLD.col_name refers to a column of an existing row before it is updated or deleted. NEW.col_name refers to the column of a new row to be inserted or an existing row after it is updated.`